# Convert html table to json nice format

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read the table with with pandas to get all results but i had no success.
This is what i've got so far.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'http://www.fundamentus.com.br/resultado.php'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
fundamentus = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


dfs = pd.read_html(fundamentus.text)
print(type(dfs))

table = dfs[0]
table.to_json('table.json')
```

But the json keys have been generated per column and not per row.

I'm new with python but this is making me get crazy.

I also tried to make a dictorinary using beautiful soup, but found pandas more easy which gave me the table, but the json export is totally messed.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the `orient` parameter in the `to_json` function. Passing `"index"` will create an object with indexes as keys, which seems like what you are looking for:

```
table.to_json('table.json', orient='index')
```

You can look in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) at the different options you can pass to the `orient` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply transpose the table before writing:

```
table_trans = table.T
table_trans.to_json('table.json')
```